# Adding/printing multiple values to queue

Tags: python

How can I add multiple items to a queue and print them in the same line. For example:

```
q = queue.Queue()

item_num = str(1)
msg = "This list contians:"
list_var = ["a","b","c"]

q.put(item_num, msg, list_var)
while not q.empty():
    print(q.get())
```

However, the output is the first thing put into the queue which is `1`. How can I put and print multiple items into a queue and keep them stored together?

Comment: If you're doing this in a single thread, `queue.Queue` is a bad queue to use. `queue.Queue` is specifically designed as an inter-thread communication mechanism, with interface decisions and overhead corresponding to that use case. Within a single thread, `collections.deque` is a better queue.

Comment: You can't add multiple items to a queue with a single `put` call. Your `msg` and `list_var` values are not being added, they are being regarded as `block` and `timeout` values.

Comment: I have 6 threads in total. I was just using the code above as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

> Queue.put(item[, block[, timeout]])

So you have to put items into the queue one by one.